# Trop Keyboard Stickers

Tags: product-recommendation

Quite a simple [product-recommendation question]: where would I find keyboard stickers for trop, including all te'amim from throughout Tana"ch ?

Background: I have a custom keyboard layout for Hebrew typography (mainly for setting a siddur, although I'd like to be able to do more) and I always have difficulty remembering which key combo is connected to each trop, due to the large number of options.

Comment: If you don't end up finding them, you could always go the homemade route (something like [this](https://www.amazon.com/BLANK-KEYBOARD-STICKERS-WHITE-BACKGROUND/dp/B002GS69E0) probably)

Comment: @DrShmuel that will definitely be fastest and cheapest

Comment: I still haven't recovered from when Microsoft moved the nekudos from capslock+shift+numbers to altgr+letters.